# How to print columns one at at time

Tags: c

Hi y'all I was wondering how I'd want to print just certain columns of a character pointer
for example:

```
char nums[2][10] = 
{
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
2  1  1  2  3  5  7
5  2  6  7  3  5  2
};
```

and so I was wondering how I'd parse the third column so it'd print

```
3
1
6
```

I tried doing printf("%s",nums[0]); but the print statement would print all the numbers or if I did something like printf("%s",nums[2]); then it'd print just

```
5 2 6 7 3 5 2
```

Thanks!

Comment: `printf("%c%c%c\n", nums[0][7], nums[1][7], nums[2][7]);`

Comment: You have to have commas between your values.  It looks like you're trying to use a Matlab syntax, but that does not apply to C.

Comment: Also, in your example, you've allocated space for 20 chars, but have 21 in your initialiser list.

Comment: As it stands the code shown is no C code, as it won't compile using a (standard) C compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char nums[2][10] = 
{
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
2  1  1  2  3  5  7
5  2  6  7  3  5  2
};
```

is not correct. You cannot declare an array of two 10-element arrays and then try to put three 7-element arrays in it. First there are too many elements, and second, the 3rd array will overflow the bounds of the construct. Also you are populating a `char` array with integers. Make sure your data types match your input. Your declaration should look like this:

```c
int nums[3][7] = 
{
 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
 {2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7},
 {5, 2, 6, 7, 3, 5, 2}
}
```

Now that we've covered that, you can consider this tidbit of code that will print out just the 3rd column, but you can modify it to read in the column to print into a variable and compare that to the value of `i` instead of hard-coding it to be the 3rd column (use 2 for zero-indexing).

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)    //for each "column"
{
  if(i == 2)                    //if we're at the 3rd 0-indexed column
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)   //cycle through the rows
    {
      printf("%d\n", nums[j][i]); //print the number in that position
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to declare your array properly:

```
char nums[3][10] =   // There are 3 rows, not 2
{
    {1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7},  // Use { } for each row
    {2,  1,  1,  2,  3,  5,  7},  // Separate values with commas
    {5,  2,  6,  7,  3,  5,  2}
};
```

---

Then its:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char nums[3][10] = 
    {
        {1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7},
        {2,  1,  1,  2,  3,  5,  7},
        {5,  2,  6,  7,  3,  5,  2}
    };


   for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
   {
       printf("%d\n", nums[i][2]); // Print the 3rd value (index 2), from each row (i)
   }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4288KB
3
1
6
```